# How to get a total value from an ArrayList of enums

Tags: java, arraylist, enums

I've have an `ArrayList<Herbs>` which stores these `enum`s below

```
public enum Herbs{
    OLD_SPICE(20),
    PURPLE_LOTUS(50);

    private final int points;

    Herbs(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
}
```

and my array list

```
herbs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Herbs.OLD_SPICE, Herbs.PURPLE_LOTUS));
```

how can I can collects the point values of this enums in this ArrayList? So far I've tried to this but really couldn't make it work.

```
public int getTotalPoints(ArrayList<Herbs> herbs) {
    ArrayList<Herbs> enumValues = Arrays.asList(herbs.values());
}
```

This is my second week in Java. My goal is to get a total value of points from `herbs` , something like `reduce()` method in JavaScript.

Comment: "So far I've tried to write a stream method but really couldn't make it work." please add that to your question so we can fix it.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I've added, sorry if it looks horrendous

Comment: @cetins Failure is a part of a process. If you had satisfactory code, there wouldn't a question, right?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thanks, I've also realized the method wasn't a stream, so i've fixed my question again

Comment: As a side note, if you don't need an `ArrayList` specifically and if you don't need to subsequently add elements to the list you can swap `herbs new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Herbs.OLD_SPICE, Herbs.PURPLE_LOTUS));` with a more concise `herbs = List.of(Herbs.OLD_SPICE, Herbs.PURPLE_LOTUS);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my goal is to get a ***total value*** of points from herbs , something like `reduce()` method in **JavaScript**.

In Java, we have a notion of *Stream* - which basically a mean of iteration over a source of data, which could be a collection, array, string, etc. I suggest you to have a look this [*tutorial created by Oracle*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html). Since your background is JavaScript, your prior knowledge might be a support in exploring streams. I guess some operations offered by Stream API like `map`, `reduce`, `forEach` would look vaguely familiar to you.

But keep in mind that *streams* **doesn't** act like plain loops. Hence, under the hood, `Stream.map()` is not doing precisely the same thing as `Array.map()` in JavaScript.

There are two general forms of reduction in the Stream API represented by the `collect()`, which is used for mutable reduction, and `reduce()`, which is meant to perform fold operation on a stream. And we also have several specialized reduction forms like `max()`, `count()`, `sum()`.

`sum()` - as its name suggests, produces the total **sum** of elements, and can be used in a *primitive stream*. You can do the same thing using `reduce()`, but it would make your code more verbose and less expressive.

#### Implementation

You can extract the points from each `Herbs` member by applying `mapToInt()` which returns an `IntStream` (*primitive stream of `int`-valued elements*), and then apply `sum()` to obtain the total.

```
int totalPoints = herbs.stream()
    .mapToInt(Herbs::getPoints)
    .sum();
```

***Sidenote:** usually, names of classes (and is a special form class) are singular. If an instance of a class is meant to represent a single object, a singular noun would be more suitable for its name. For example, `Month` and `DayOfWeek` enum-classes from the `java.time` package.*

Answer (score 2):

Stream's Sum collector is the shortest way:

```java
int sum = herbs.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(Herbs::getPoints));
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an example: https://www.online-java.com/Qy3C2igd0t

```
var herbs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Herbs.OLD_SPICE, Herbs.PURPLE_LOTUS));
System.out.println(herbs.stream().map(x -> x.getPoints()).reduce(0, Integer::sum));
```